# extracting data from CSV file using a reference

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file with several hundred organism IDs and a second csv file with several thousand organism IDs and additional characteristics (taxonomic information, abundances per sample, etc)

I am trying to write a code that will extract the information from the larger csv using the smaller csv file as a reference.  Meaning it will look at both smaller and larger files, and if the IDs are in both files, it will extract all the information form the larger file and write that in a new file (basically write the entire row for that ID).

so far I have written the following, and while the code does not error out on me, I get a blank file in the end and I don't exactly know why. I am a graduate student that knows some simple coding but I'm still very much a novice,

thank you

```
import sys
import csv
import os.path


SparCCnames=open(sys.argv[1],"rU")
OTU_table=open(sys.argv[2],"rU")
new_file=open(sys.argv[3],"w")
Sparcc_OTUs=csv.writer(new_file)
d=csv.DictReader(SparCCnames)
ids=csv.DictReader(OTU_table)

for record in ids:
    idstopull=record["OTUid"]
    if idstopull[0]=="OTUid":
        continue
    if idstopull[0] in d:
        new_id.writerow[idstopull[0]]

SparCCnames.close()
OTU_table.close()
new_file.close()
```

Comment: d is an iterator and you have drained it the first time through the loop you need to record everything in d in some data structure or reopen it.

Comment: You should be getting an error saying that "new_id" has not been declared.  Also, note that dictionaries do not  contain duplicate keys so if there are duplicates in the file, the dictionary will only contain the last duplicate in the file.  I would also suggest that you print idstopull[0] as you compare it to the key ("OTUid"), so unless it is in the record twice, that condition will never be met.

Comment: @CurlyJoe it's an iterator over dictionaries only a duplicate fieldname will cause an issue with multiple keys.

Comment: `idstopull[0] in d` will never be true you are comparing the data in the field `OTUid` with the dictionaries returned by the `d` iterator.

Comment: @achampion  can you provide an example for how I would record everything in d? Would creating a list work?  Also, I wasn't sure how to  make the statement that if the ids are in d then write the entire row in new_file. Any suggestions for how to write that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for your help. I played with things and consulted with an advisor, and finally got a working script. I am posting it in case it helps someone else in the future.

Thanks!

```
import sys
import csv

input_file = csv.DictReader(open(sys.argv[1], "rU")) #has all info

ref_list = csv.DictReader(open(sys.argv[2], "rU")) #reference list

output_file = csv.DictWriter(
open(sys.argv[3], "w"), input_file.fieldnames) #to write output file with headers

output_file.writeheader() #write headers in output file

white_list={} #create empty dictionary
for record in ref_list: #for every line in my reference list
    white_list[record["Sample_ID"]] = None #store into the dictionary the  ID's as keys

for record in input_file: #for every line in my input file
    record_id = record["Sample_ID"] #store ID's into variable record_id
    if (record_id in white_list): #if the ID is in the reference list
        output_file.writerow(record)   #write the entire row into a new file
    else:   #if it is not in my reference list
        continue  #ignore it and continue iterating through the file
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do in your code but you can try this:

```
def csv_to_dict(csv_file_path):
    csv_file = open(csv_file_path, 'rb')
    csv_file.seek(0)
    sniffdialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(csv_file.read(10000), delimiters='\t,;')
    csv_file.seek(0)
    dict_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file, dialect=sniffdialect)
    csv_file.seek(0)
    dict_data = []
    for record in dict_reader:
        dict_data.append(record)

    csv_file.close()

    return dict_data


def dict_to_csv(csv_file_path, dict_data):
    csv_file = open(csv_file_path, 'wb')
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file, dialect='excel')

    headers = dict_data[0].keys()
    writer.writerow(headers)

    # headers must be the same with dat.keys()
    for dat in dict_data:
        line = []
        for field in headers:
            line.append(dat[field])
        writer.writerow(line)

    csv_file.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    big_csv = csv_to_dict('/path/to/big_csv_file.csv')
    small_csv = csv_to_dict('/path/to/small_csv_file.csv')
    output = []
    for s in small_csv:
        for b in big_csv:
            if s['id'] == b['id']:
                output.append(b)
    if output:
        dict_to_csv('/path/to/output.csv', output)
    else:
        print "Nothing."
```

Hope that will help.

Comment: I didn't see where the OP was having a problem with dialects, all the dialect handling seems to unnecessarily complicate the answer.

Comment: Those are just utility functions I wrote to be able to re-use in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the data into a data structure, assuming OTUid is unique you can store this into a dictionary for fast lookup:

```
with open(sys.argv[1],"rU") as SparCCnames:
    d = csv.DictReader(SparCCnames)
    fieldnames = d.fieldnames
    data = {i['OTUid']: i for i in d}

with open(sys.argv[2],"rU") as OTU_table, open(sys.argv[3],"w") as new_file:
    Sparcc_OTUs = csv.DictWriter(new_file, fieldnames)
    ids = csv.DictReader(OTU_table)
    for record in ids:
        if record['OTUid'] in data:
            Sparcc_OTUs.writerow(data[record['OTUid']])
```

Comment: thank you for the example script. Can I ask what d2 should be? When I try out this script I get an error that d2 is not defined.

Comment: typo - fixed, I changed my variable names to match your original variable names with addition of `data`. I would look at a style guide for python because your variable names are hard to read.

Comment: thank you very much! But this script wrote an output file that has only the OTUids, which is essentially the the same as the the reference file (SparCCnames). I need to also extract all of the information from the larger file (OTU_table), so I want to write the entire row.  How can I do that?

Comment: Which file has the details and which file has just the ids? Based on your logic I assumed SparCCnames has all the data and if that is the case this should write out all the data in new_file. Try printing out `data[record['OTUid']]` and make sure the data is there. If I have assumed wrong swap sys.argv[1] with sys.argv[2] and vice versa.

Comment: thank you. I did the switch as you suggested and now it is an empty file again. I printed data and it seems that it is an empty {}, so my output file is empty because there is nothing stored in the data variable. I'm not sure why this would happen when all I did was change sys.argv[1] with sys.argv[2] and vice versa